# The For loop function won't work but gives the same result without any messaging error

Tags: excel, excel-2010

[Once the date filter in column L is applied then J1 counts the number of items visible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyXGF.png) In the provided code below, I'm trying a date loop where i can go back in time and look at a specific month. E.g look at the month previous to the one i may be looking at and so on.

I have tried making small sub macros that i coulmd call on once the main macro finishes to run but i am not able to put them together such that the small macros are called in order and executed one after the other.

```
Option Explicit

Sub trial_trial_Table()

    Dim StartDate As Long, EndDate As Long, mois As Long, nextmonth As Long, z As Long, x As Long, i As Long

    z = StartDate
    StartDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1)
    x = EndDate
    EndDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 0, 0)

    z = 1

    For z = StartDate - 1 To StartDate

        z = z - 1

        x = 0

        For x = 0 To 12 'EndDate

            x = x - 1

            StartDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 1, 1) 'The first day of the previous month:
            EndDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) - 0, 0) 'The last day of the previous month:

            Sheets("Essais").Select

            ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$4822").AutoFilter Field:=12, _
                                                    Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, _
                                                    Operator:=xlAnd, _
                                                    Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate
        Next x

    Next z

End Sub
```

I would like the macro to function. If you may please help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what you are trying to accomplish. If want to call a "small" sub inside of another sub, you can do it with the command call:

```
Call NameOfSmallSub()
```

That way, you can call any number of macros in a row.

A couple of hints to get your code going:

Each long variable holds the value 0, when initialised (your Dim command). So when you assign StartDate to x right after the initialisation, you could just write "x = 0" instead. Since you set another value to x after that without using x in between, this assignment is not needed at all.

Also, when you substract 0 from a number this has no effect on it. So instead of writing "Month(Date) - 0" this would be exactly the same "Month(Date)". I am not sure, what you expect from a DateSerial return with day "0". I would advise you to debug your code line be line and observe all of your variables to see what is actually happening.

Your loop will run forever, since you decrement your looping variable x every time. Your loop can never reach its end like that. But what do you need your loop for anyhow?

It seems, you are not familiar with vba scripting. Probably you can achieve in excel what you want even without vba scripting? I would ask a new question and descrive what I want to have and ask for a good way to achieve that.

I hope this helps a little.

Comment: what i want to accomplish is the following, filter automatically column (12) according to the current month in such that the macro can go: current month-1=april, current month-2=march, current month-3=february and so on.....

Comment: If you are more specific, it will help. How does your table look like? What do mean with "[whatever] can go: current mounth-1 = april" and so on?

Comment: Hey @bejo i've added some information as requested, hope it helps and thanks for yours efforts.

Comment: @Jemmy Please explain, what you do or want to do in excel step by step. Probably then I will have a chance to understand what you need. What do you want to have or see at the end when the macro has finished running?